# Como detectar a conexão com a internet via javascript?

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma maneira de "saber", via `javascript`, se a conexão com a internet foi perdida?

Por exemplo, para tentar uma reconexão com websocket, caso detecte que a conexão com a internet foi perdida e, depois, foi reestabelecida.

Comment: `navigator.onLine` funciona de verdade?

Comment: Cria uma rota do seu site para usar como `ping`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`navigator.onLine` funciona de verdade; No entanto "onLine" não se refere a uma conexão à internet, mas uma ligação qualquer. Se o usuário estiver ligado a uma VPN, mas essa VPN não tem internet - `navigator.onLine` retornará `true` também;

A melhor solução será fazer um pedido de `GET` por ajax a um qualquer site e se essa ligação não falhar sabes que o usuário (muito provavelmente) está online.

Comment: @danguilherme bem visto! :)